# Portable Air Conditioning Venting

Tags: air-conditioning

I don't have a window and was wondering if I can vent a portable air conditioner down the heating vent for the room?

Comment: The warm discharge air has to be discharged to the outside to get rid of the heat and moisture. The heating vent goes to the furnace and not to the outside. NO, you can't vent the air into the heating vent.

Answer (score 2):

No, this is a bad idea. The exhaust from the air conditioner is high humidity. You'll be creating the perfect environment for mold growth in the air handler at the other end of he heating duct.